# 32-bit program has a dependency on a 64-bit library

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit

when I type `ldd helloworld` I get this as one of the dependencies :

```
libboost_system.so.1.55.0 => not found
```

It turns out, though, that this is a 64-bit library whereas `helloworld` is a 32-bit program. Then, the output error I get when trying to run the application is:

```
./sayhelloworld: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What can I do?

Thanks y'all

Comment: Is your system 32-bit or 64-bit (`uname -m`)? how did you install the program? what is the output of `apt-cache policy libboost-system-dev`?

Comment: my system is a 64-bit one and I already added i386 architecture.

Comment: the output of what you have asked:
Installed: 1.54.0.1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.54.0.1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.54.0.1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary programs require shared libraries compiled for the same CPU architecture, in this case i386, Intel's 32-bit architecture. On Ubuntu installations using amd64, AMD's and Intel's 64-bit architecture, you can install the latter in addition to the "native" architecture.

### Preparation

If you haven't done so, enable the "foreign" architecture and update the package repository index:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

### Package installation

`libboost_system.so.1.55.0`, the shared library in question comes in the package `libboost-system1.55.0` (see also [How do I find the package that provides a file?](/q/481/175814)). You can ask the package manager to install a package for a specific architecture if you append a colon (`:`) and the name of the architecture:

```
sudo apt install libboost-system1.55.0:i386
```